# Importing binary applications

Tags: rhel5

I have a server that has  no dev tools on it (e.g. no *gcc*).
In addition the server has no direct link to the outside world (e.g. no *apt-get*).
The above could not be changed - as an organizational security demand.

The only way to interact with the server is via *ssh / scp*.
I wish to import a certain application to it (SysStats).
The server runs on top of (what used to be) a normal RHEL.

Is there a way to import binary applications to,

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by downloading the packages on another machine then copying them to the target server and installing them. However, it may be a tedious task as you need to download all package dependences.

This is the only option if your server is not allowed to initiate any connection to the Internet. Otherwise, you can setup a proxy server on non-standard port and configure your server to use it. Under debina/ubuntu, there is apt-cacher which can be used as proxy for apt-get.